# Overwriting vector<vector<> > and segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, adjacency-list

I'm trying to write a program in which at each step of a loop I create an adjacency list representing a graph that changes in time.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>                                              
#include <fstream>         
#include <string>           
#include <sstream>         
#include <vector>         
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>                                           
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>                  
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>                 
#include <boost/random/uniform_int.hpp>                        
#include <boost/random/uniform_real.hpp>
#include <boost/random/exponential_distribution.hpp>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;

 typedef boost::mt19937_64 ENG; // use Mersenne Twister 19937 as PRNG engine
 typedef boost::uniform_int<> DIST_INT; // define uniform distribution of integers
 typedef boost::uniform_real<> DIST_REAL; // define uniform distribution of reals on [0,1)
 typedef boost::exponential_distribution<> DIST_EXP; // define exponential distribution
 typedef boost::variate_generator<ENG,DIST_INT> VARIATE_INT;
 typedef boost::variate_generator<ENG,DIST_REAL> VARIATE_REAL;
 typedef boost::variate_generator<ENG,DIST_EXP> VARIATE_EXP;

int main()
{  
 const unsigned int random_seed = time(NULL);
 // ======= initialize BOOST machines
 ENG eng(random_seed);
 DIST_INT dist_int;
 DIST_REAL dist_rand(0,1);
 DIST_EXP dist_exp;
 VARIATE_INT randint(eng,dist_int); //random integer. use as: randint(N)
 VARIATE_REAL rand(eng,dist_rand); //random float on [0,1[. use as: rand()
 VARIATE_EXP randexp(eng,dist_exp); //random exponentially distributed float.
 int N = 500, Tmax=200000, v, w;
 float p = 0.2, s;
 vector<vector<int> > contact_list;
 for(int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
 {
  contact_list.resize(N, vector<int>());
  v = 1;
  w = -1;
  while(v < N)
    {
      s = rand();
      w += 1 + int(log(1-s)/log(1-p));
      while((w >= v) && (v < N))
       {
        w = w - v;
        v += 1;
       }
      if (v < N)
       {
        contact_list[v].push_back(w);
        contact_list[w].push_back(v);
       }
    }
 }
}
```

However at some point I get segmentation fault. In fact I think this may not be the correct way to overwrite a vector. I also add that I would like to change N_nodes at each step. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are creating a new vector of vectors *each time through the loop*. I don't see how this is doing you any good. Apparently `N_nodes` has the same problem. Perhaps you should be declaring these variables at a higher scope, like *outside* of the loop?

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code you didn't post.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to post a minimal and complete example

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I added a minimal and complete example and I made some small modifications but still I get segmentation fault!

Comment: Try accessing the vector using .at(), or provide valgrind with the switches to point out the erroring line. (compile with -g).

Comment: Thank you @ErikAlapää for your advice. I found out the problem: sometimes rand gives 1, which is not good because it feeds a 0 in the log!

Answer (score -2):

For the segmentation fault part you can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to try and find out what operation in your code is writing at an invalid location.

Also you can catch Segmantation fault, with the use of signal, but it's not a good practice to catch a segmentation fault